# Effacing of a gray line for a table HTML

Tags: html, css

In my HTML table, I would like to efface a grey line just at the top from my datas.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XW0fR.png)

I don't see where this gray colored line comes from?

```
<tr *ngIf="currentIndex === i">
   <td colspan="3"></td>
   <td colspan="6">
      <ng-container>
         <table
            class="table table-striped"
            style="width:120%; text-align: center;">
            <tr>
               <td scope="col" style="width: 4%; ">Date échéance - {{ strike.key.dateEcheanceFinale | dateddmmyyyy }}  </td>
               <td scope="col" style="width: 4%; ">Coéficient cotation - {{ strike.key.coefficientCotation }} </td>
               <td scope="col" style="width: 4%; ">Place - {{ strike.key.placelabel }} </td>
            </tr>
         </table>
      </ng-container>
   </td>
   <td colspan="3"></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should do like this border:none; for the inner table:

```
<tr *ngIf="currentIndex === i">
<td colspan="3"></td>
<td colspan="6">
<ng-container>
         <table
            class="table table-striped"
            style="width:120%; text-align: center;border:none;">
            <tr>
               <td scope="col" style="width: 4%; ">Date échéance - {{ strike.key.dateEcheanceFinale | dateddmmyyyy }}  </td>
               <td scope="col" style="width: 4%; ">Coéficient cotation - {{ strike.key.coefficientCotation }} </td>
               <td scope="col" style="width: 4%; ">Place - {{ strike.key.placelabel }} </td>
            </tr>
         </table>
      </ng-container>
   </td>
   <td colspan="3"></td>
</tr>
```